# How do I prevent launcher from showing a drive icon for each mounted partition

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

I have a single disk composed of a few partitions, that I'd like to be mounted when I log in, just like the system partition is.
I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. It was working fine before, by adding this command line to the start up applications

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2;
/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb3;
/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb4;
```

However now with 16.04, though it also mounts them, the file explorer (called 'Files') doesn't behave the same way at all: whenever I open a directory in one of the user partitions, the mounted drives are added as a separate icon in the unity launch bar, as though I inserted a usb key for example, instead of being part of the File application windows. It is very annoying to have multiple icons in the unity launch bar for basically explorer windows.

How can I go back to the previous situation ?

Comment: Why was your title different than the question?

Comment: I have same issue. I mount a partition at `/sdb/sdb1` to something like `/home/mnt/storage` and each time I open a folder from this partition, the hard drive (volume) icon appears, but I would prefer the Files icon, like previous versions of Ubuntu. The only difference for me is that I used to be running 12.04 and now I'm running 16.04. I'm using the same set up procedures, eg, `fstab`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using dconf-editor by blacklisting UUIDs solved the problem for me (i.e. worked for permanently attached storage / partitions).

If you don't have it installed already, run `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Navigate to com → canonical → Unity → devices and enter the 'UUID-Label' (i.e. UUID and the Label of the drive separated by a single dash) of the mount in `blacklist`. The blacklist is an array of strings and any drive / partitions added to blacklist will not be shown in the launcher by default.

Just use the UUID of your mount inside the square bracket and the single quote marks. 
To know the UUID of drives run `sudo blkid -o list` or `sudo blkid` in a Terminal.

Below is an example of how the blacklist should look..

```
 ['6D7B3DA124CBC7E1-D', '9496GB2587CB06A8-H', '2AD455A9D425771B-G', 'FEBEE8ECBEE12E33-Windows-8']
```

If any partition in your machine doesn’t have a 'label' assigned to it, use Gparted to assign a label first before blacklisting the UUID.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only work as long as the partitions are connected. On the next connect, they will appear again.